# Can CiviCRM limit the number of event registrations for each member?

Tags: civievent, civimember

Can CiviCRM limit the number of event registrations for each member?

We have an event where they receive an automatic discount (because they are a member). However, we don't want them to buy the tickets for others at that price.

So we only want them to be able to register for each event, once. Is this possible?

Jon-man

Comment: You may want to restate the question as you deal with three topics: discount, limiting number of participants and membership.

Answer (score 2):

CiviDiscount has functionality that limits the number of times a discount can be used. So if you create one-use discount codes / member, that might meet your need.

The automatic discount for members probably does not have a limit functionality, though that might be a useful addition